# Django & ZeroMQ - how to keep the ZMQ context? + issues with nginx/uwsgi multiple processes?

Tags: python, django, nginx, zeromq

I have a Django application, and I would like to make ZeroMQ calls during views. I would like to initialize the context once and have it globally available.

My question is twofold:

- How can I initialize a context at the start-up of Django and cause it to be globally shared?
- Does the multi-processing of uwsgi/nginx cause *n* completely separate instances, or does it do a fork, causing me to require *n* separate contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Use a process [manager](http://supervisord.org/) for running separate application server (Django) and Zeromq server process using custom manage [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) that will solve your situation correctly.
NOTE: Using custom manage command for Zeromq server ( for running as a subscriber or other persistent daemon Zeromq device profiles), you can access Django models or APIs.